# IE8 web debug toolbar and CSS/JS

Tags: symfony

I'm working with Symfony2 and I emulate IE8 with VMWare.
I have a problem with the web debug toolbar and its display.

I don't know why the toolbar is not working good.

Maybe there'is some JS problem but I don't find anything. If I click on any item, I have the details page but there, I have a JS bug that's why I think about a JS bug for my toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Did you have any js errors?

Comment: Nothing. I'm a bit lost with this bug. When I look into the source code, in IE8, I don't have the <!-- START of Symfony2 Web Debug Toolbar --> saying that the toolbar is loading and the CSS is at display:none.
I think there are some issues somewhere but where ?

Comment: Does it display ok with Chrome (or any other browser) with VMWare?

Comment: It looks ok with Chrome under VMWare.

Comment: It looks the same for me in IE8 locally.

Comment: Same here, IE8 is a smoker